# Getting a count for the first six months and last six months of FYear

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to count all patients who had a service in both the first six months of the year and the last six months of the the fiscal year. This is what I have come up with, but not certain that it will be completely clean.

```
with sd as
 (
select  cln.cln_urn, MAX(srv_date) As Last_D, MIN(srv_date) AS First_d
    from cw_domain dmn
     inner join cw_service srv on srv.srv_dmn_fk=dmn.dmn_pk
     inner join cw_client cln on cln.cln_pk=srv.srv_cln_fk
     inner join cw_subservice sbs on sbs.sbs_pk=srv.srv_sbs_fk
     inner join cw_service_category ct on ct.srv_ct_rpk=sbs.sbs_srv_ct_rfk
WHERE srv.srv_date >= '03/01/2015'
      and srv.srv_date <= '02/29/2016'
      and srv_ct_rpk = '002'
      group by cln_urn
      having MAX(srv_date)>= MIN(srv_date)+180

      )  

select count (distinct cln_urn)
from sd
```

What is being researched in this report is the number of clients who are keeping up with their treatment. In order for our client base to be considered 'in care' they must see their doctor twice a year: once in the first half and again in the second half of the year

Comment: - tell us what dates you want to select - what do you mean by first 6 months of THE YEAR, if you then say last 6 months of FISCAL YEAR - very perplexing   you might need to select record from first half of yera, then INNER JOIN to record from second half of year - if both exist - then row selected

Comment: look at the year. Those date are between March 1 2015 and February 29 2016. FY year can be either FY or CY. I am doing FY. The patients needs to have had a visit in both the first six months of the specified year and the last six months of the specified year to qualify.

Comment: 0 down vote
 

yeah I know, sorry I was wrong - you could select from the first half, then use IF EXISTS(select ..from second half for same person) to complete selection

Answer (score 0):

If You want to count how many services each client has had, You need to use count function.

```
select HalfOfYear
     , NumOfPatients = count(Client)
from (select  
         cln_urn as Client
        ,case when datepart(q,srv_date) in (1,2) then 'FirstHalf'   
              when datepart(q,srv_date) in (3,4) then 'SecondHalf'  
              end as HalfOfYear
     from cw_domain dmn
     inner join cw_service srv on srv.srv_dmn_fk=dmn.dmn_pk
     inner join cw_client cln on cln.cln_pk=srv.srv_cln_fk
     inner join cw_subservice sbs on sbs.sbs_pk=srv.srv_sbs_fk
     inner join cw_service_category ct on ct.srv_ct_rpk=sbs.sbs_srv_ct_rfk
     where srv.srv_date >= '03/01/2015'
      and srv.srv_date <= '02/29/2016'
      and srv_ct_rpk = '002'

      ) as x
group by HalfOfYear
```

Comment: datepart is returning quarters based on calendar year only not fiscal year

Comment: I agree but whe can change datepart to another condition like srv_date between ... and ... then First half  an do on...

Comment: Close. What I need is the count for all clients who had a visit in the first half AND second half. Not the number in the first and second half. I'll look at this further though.

Comment: What is being researched in this report is the number of clients who are keeping up with their treatment. In order for our client base to be considered 'in care' they must see their doctor twice a year: once in the first half and again in the second half of the year.

Comment: Now i understand Your need :) my query can present want You want, when we modify subselect by adding inner join and change a little date condition in where clause

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Just swap out the @from and @thru with your dates.

```
WITH sd AS
(
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        cln.cln_urn, 
        CASE
            WHEN srv.srv_date < DATEADD(MONTH, 6, @from) THEN 1
            WHEN srv.srv_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, 6, @from) THEN 2
            END AS 'half'
    FROM
        cw_domain dmn
        INNER JOIN cw_service AS srv 
            ON srv.srv_dmn_fk = dmn.dmn_pk
        INNER JOIN cw_client cln 
            ON cln.cln_pk = srv.srv_cln_fk
        INNER JOIN cw_subservice sbs 
            ON sbs.sbs_pk = srv.srv_sbs_fk
        INNER JOIN cw_service_category ct 
            ON ct.srv_ct_rpk = sbs.sbs_srv_ct_rfk
    WHERE 
        srv.srv_date >= @from
        AND srv.srv_date <= @thru
        AND srv_ct_rpk = '002'
)

SELECT
    COUNT(cln.cln_urn)
FROM
    sd AS fh
    JOIN sd AS sh
        ON fh.cln_urn = sh.cln_urn
WHERE
    fh.half = 1
    AND sh.half = 2
```